# Ionic framework facebook login integration

Tags: android, ios, facebook, ionic-framework

I am playing with Ionic framework and wondering if it's possible to implement the following with Ionic:

Perform a login with Facebook by opening the native Facebook application on both iOS/Android (not the in-app browser thing) and ask for permission for my app then if the user approves it I want his accessToken to be sent to my application.
Is that doable ?

I have gone through a lot of documentation and as far as I can see the only way to achieve that is to use in-app browser where the user approves the permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `$cordovaFacebook` module; a successful login returns the accessToken.

here is an example using the `accessToken` to login to Parse.com

http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/ionic-framework-facebook-login-with-parse

```
  $cordovaFacebook.login(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"])
    .then(function(success) {
      // { id: "634565435",
      //   lastName: "bob"
      //   ...
      // }
    }, function (error) {
      // error
    });
```

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/

Comment: Brilliant ! Thanks Aaron :)